# How to make sure a file is closed before renaming it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm opening word documents using Appword.documents.open and closing them with appword.quit. Then in a function called ProcessData, the application renames the document.

The problem I'm getting is that the file is not closed before the code tries to rename it. How can I make sure the word document is closed before trying to rename it?

```
WordDoc = AppWord.Documents.Open(filepath + filename)
txtFileContents.Text = WordDoc.Content.Text
AppWord.Quit()

ProcessData(txtFileContents.Text, filepath, filename)
```

This is what renames the document in the ProcessData function:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(fPath + fName, NewName + ".doc")
```

Comment: This is bizarre code. Anyway you check for errors and if there is one you retry the command until it works. Do while err.number =0:My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(fPath + fName, NewName + ".doc"):If err.number <> 0 then: err.clear:else:exit do:Loop:

Comment: Looks like VB.Net code, not VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't just be using the application Quit () method to close the document. Use:

```
WordDoc.Close
Set WordDoc = Nothing
```

Then call the Quit method.

Comment: What will that achieve. It goes out of scope at the end of the sub and is automatically set to nothing. If you set something to nothing you cannot call anything on it.

Comment: @tonybd I have had problems with earlier versions of Office applications where this kind of thing was very important indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
WordDoc.Close()
AppWord.Quit()
AppWord=nothing
WordDoc=nothing
```